# How do I speed up row selection in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a pretty large data set `raw`, I originally select the rows like this:

```
raw = np.array(Some Matrix)
selected = [r for r in raw if r[1] == '20130525' and r[2] < 120000]
```

But this is really slow , anyone know how do speed it up using Numpy's build-in functions ?

Answer (score 1):

This would be the standard numpythonic approach:

```
selected = raw[(raw[:, 1] == '20130525') & (raw[:, 2] == 120000)]
```

But the speeding up is probably going to be meager if you have an array of `object` type, as the mixed data types suggest. What exactly are you dealing with? Could you use a recarray instead?

Comment: I don't know why, but this is even slower than my `[r for r in raw if r[1] == 'xxx']`

Comment: Check what `raw.dtype` is. If it is of type `object` you are sabotaging yourself by not using numpy the way it is supposed to be used: with arrays of a single, common data type. The alternative is to at least have all columns share a data type (i.e. use a record array). If you provide more information on what's in your array, and how do you build it, it may be possible to redo your approach and give you your the speed you are looking for.

Comment: @MrROY, the `&&` is the and operator in C, JavaScript and others but it is not an operator in Python. The `&` is the bitwise and operator which works on integer and booleans, and also on np.ndarrays with integers or booleans. In cases like this example, I sometimes prefer to use the function `np.logical_and` above `&` because it needs less parentheses and is sometimes easier to read.